# Create a Spark pool by user by default on Zeppelin Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I am working with Spark inside Zeppelin in a collaborative environment. So we have only one interpreter and many users are using this interpreter. For this reason, I defined it using `instantiation per user` in `scoped mode`.

With this configuration, a user job X await the resource allocated by jobs of another users.

To change this behavior and allow jobs from different users to execute at the same time, I defined the Spark configuration (on Zeppelin interpreter configurations) `spark.scheduler.mode` equal to `FAIR`. To make desired effect, the user need to define manually, on your notebook, your own Spark pool (jobs from different pools can be executed at same time: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application) with this code:

```
sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "pool1")
```

Ps.: After one hour, the interpreter shutdown. If users forget to execute this command on next time, they fall in default pool, what is not good.

What I want to know: **Is possible to set a Spark user pool automatically when he executes your paragraphs without manual efforts every time?**

If there is another way to do this, please let me know if it's possible.

Comment: in 7.01 there was an **experimental** feature called [Interpreter Execution Hooks](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/manual/interpreterexechooks.html). It sounds like it is run for each paragraph, but for your example it probably won't matter. Could this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I was reading about it and seems to be a approach. The only drawback is that the end users (zeppelin users) will need to worry about infrastructure issues. Thanks!